# Is there an SQL (postgresql) command to access to the previous value that does not equal the current one?

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, function

I have table that looks like the following, with many emails as well. The column `product` can contain `NULL` or `No` values.

| email | date | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:31:18 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:32:28 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:33:48 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:34:23 | NULL |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:10 | Product2 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:48 | Product2 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:36:09 | No |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:37:45 | No |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:38:10 | No |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:39:28 | Product3 |

My intent is to assign to the `NULL` or `No` products the previous values of the `product` column that are not `NULL` or `No`. Like:

| email | date | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:31:18 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:32:28 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:33:48 | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:34:23 | **Product1** |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:10 | Product2 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:48 | Product2 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:36:09 | **Product2** |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:37:45 | **Product2** |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:38:10 | **Product2** |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:39:28 | Product3 |

I have tried using WINDOWS functions like

```
SELECT email,
    date,
    product,
    CASE    
        WHEN product='No' THEN lag(product) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY date)
        WHEN product IS NULL THEN lag(product) OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY date)
    END AS product2
    FROM table;
```

Obtaining

| email | date | product | product2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:31:18 | Product1 |  |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:32:28 | Product1 |  |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:33:48 | Product1 |  |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:34:23 | NULL | Product1 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:10 | Product2 |  |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:35:48 | Product2 |  |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:36:09 | No | Product2 |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:37:45 | No | No |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:38:10 | No | No |
| email1 | 2020-12-15 20:39:28 | Product3 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a subquery as the following:

```
SELECT T.email, T.date, 
   (SELECT D.product FROM table_name D 
    WHERE D.email=T.email AND D.date<=T.date AND D.product IS NOT NULL AND D.product<>'No' 
    ORDER BY D.date DESC 
    LIMIT 1) product
FROM table_name T
ORDER BY T.email, T.date
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1QjhSt4C).

Answer (score 0):

What you did is actually correct. I'd change it slightly though:

```
SELECT
    email,
    date,
    CASE WHEN product = 'No'
        OR product IS NULL THEN
        lag(product) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY date)
    ELSE
        product
    END AS product
FROM
    table_name;
```